# Frames transfer between kernel and user space

Tags: linux, communication

For CPE device solution on Linux platform, there is OAM frame with ethertype 0x8809, so what's the better solution that transfer theses frames between kernel space and user space.
1. linux net device, by socket
2. file_operations in kernel space, read and write operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose 1 (ie. `AF_PACKET` socket) if I implement the protocol stack by myself.  Your option 2 seems to me irrelevant.

But have you considered using any existing solutions?  A quick web search led me to this article:

- [linux support 802.1ag and Y1731](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568284/linux-support-802-1ag-and-y1731)